# Passing a signal from a .NET app to a Java app

Tags: java, windows, ipc

I need to pass a signal from a .NET app to a Java app. No data is required, the signal itself is enough.

The most simple way that comes to my mind is by using a named synchronization object like this:

1. The .NET app creates a certain named synchronization object A.
2. The Java app creates a certain named synchronization object A - the name is the same as in (1).
3. The Java app has a thread waiting on the object to become signaled.
4. The .NET app signals the object.
5. The Java app thread awakens and acts upon the signal reception.

At least, this how I would do it if I knew how to create a named synchronization object in Java.

But looks like Java does not have any, which I find hard to believe. Does it mean that only Windows has named synchronization objects?

So, my question is this - how do I pass a simple signal (no data) from a non Java app to a Java app on Windows? Both processes run on the same host.

**EDIT**

Motivation - I want to signal to our headless Java process to terminate itself gracefully as soon as it can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For God's sake, I just want a single 1 bit signal from a C++/C# process to a Java process and there is no simple way to do it. I can't believe it.

Forget about it, I'll just use the file system. The C++/C# code is going to create an empty file at a well known location, which the Java code is going to poll every second.

Finito, end of story.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a socket connection between your programs, and by send and receive specific pattern you can detect signal

Comment: Please, agree with me that it is much more complicated than using a named synchronization object. Do you want to say that Java does not support this concept?

Comment: ye, or perhaps it is so difficult to use , and tcp socket is very simple and reliable in every platform

Comment: "Ye" as in "Java does not support named synchronization objects" ? How  do you synchronize between two Java processes? Using messaging or TCP sockets only?

Comment: i am a c# programer, and i don't know enough knowledge about java, but i am sure that with TCP Socket you can do that

Comment: Yes, but in C#/C++ you can do it also with a named synchronization object, like Event. And it is much simpler than with a TCP socket, which is truly an overkill for a simple signal. Let me give you an example. How do you prevent a Windows application from having multiple running instances? Yes, sure, one can create a lock file and check its presence or even create a TCP socket and try to listen to it. But the easiest thing in the world is just check for an existence of a named synchronization object, like Event or Mutex. My need is similar - I want to signal a process to terminate itself.

Comment: Java does not have IPC (inter process communication) privatives.  And it does not give you access to the .net ones.  If you create a TCP port, the bind it to 127.0.0.1 then other hosts will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: @DavidRoussel - that can be used to check if the application is running. But how to signal it to shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

I second thought, that i had done before by using ICE Framework, you can download and learn the ICE Framework from here,
ICE Framework is a cross framework for communication between processes a local system or on a network.

[Download Ice Framework](http://www.zeroc.com/)